# Double integral implementation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to implement Double integral in matlab. Single integral is easy but programming for double is a bit more complicated.

The equation to be implemented is the following:

[image]

I have tried to implement the inner integral using the statement

```
t = sym('t'); a = sym('a');    
pretty(int(t*((1-t)^-2.5)*((1-a*t)^-1)))
```

But this leads to a much bigger equation and how do I evaluate the outer integral then?
Any tricks or hints regarding this?

Comment: What do the paragraph mark, dots and "a" represent?

Comment: Have you tried applying `int` multiple times?

Comment: David it was meant as end of line(call it my inexperience in Latex), What i wanted to convey was that in the integral a is equal to the value given. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: horchler i tried but with no success as matlab gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your question. The integral says that you integrate \theta out, how can it then appear in the solution? And the equation does not even depend on \theta, so it should just cancel with the \frac{1}{\pi}.

However, if you have mistyped it and you would get a number out in the end, then I guess that numerical integration could work out for you?

If so, the two integrals reduces to a sum and you can for instance use the function quad on one of them and the trapezoidal rule on the other one, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule, then it would be something like:

```
function int = integral(f,a,b,c,d)
dt = 0.001;
x = a:dt:b;
tempInt = zeros(length(x));
for i = 1:length(x)
    tempInt(i) = quad(@(y) f(x(i),y),c,d);
end
int = dt/2*(2*sum(tempInt)-tempInt(1)-tempInt(end));
```

Comment: The outer integral limits are given in radians, so 0 rad = 0 deg and \pi radian = 180 radian, so sin^2(theta) is a variable in the outer integral. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't. If I understand it correctly what you want to do is to: 
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t}{(t-1)^{2.5}(1-at)}dt d\theta. 
Because of Tonelli and Fubini you can interchange the integrals, such that: 
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{t}{(t-1)^{2.5}(1-at)} d\theta dt. = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t}{(t-1)^{2.5}(1-at)}dt.
Then nothing depends on \theta?